# Strange behavior with memcpy and "alias"

Tags: c, arrays, alias, memcpy

i'm dealing with memcpy to copy one array into another: here is the code, (i gave also the declarations)

```
.... /* s is a struct with int *t_con_cust;  */
/* bad to use an equivalent name i guess ..*/
s.t_con_cust = malloc(nb_cust*sizeof(*s.t_con_cust));
int *t_con_cust = malloc(nb_cust*sizeof(*t_con_cust));
...    
t_con_cust[0] = 1;
memcpy(s.t_con_cust, t_con_cust, nb_cust*sizeof(int));

fprintf(stdout, "s.t_con_cust[0] -> %d \n", s.t_con_cust[0]);
t_con_cust[0] = 0;
fprintf(stdout, "s.t_con_cust[0] -> %d \n", s.t_con_cust[0]);
```

The execution gave me :

> s.t_con_cust[0] -> 1
>
> s.t_con_cust[0] -> 0

which is beyond me, because when I tried with "sample code" like that

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct { 
    int *dest;
} lambda_struct;


int main(void) { 
    lambda_struct s;
    s.dest = malloc(10*sizeof(*s.dest)); 
    int *src  = malloc(10*sizeof(*src));
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
        src[i] = 1;

    memcpy(s.dest, src, 10);

    fprintf(stdout, "dest[0] -> %d \n", s.dest[0]);
    src[0] = 0;
    fprintf(stdout, "dest[0] -> %d \n", s.dest[0]);

    free(src);
    free(s.dest);

    return 0;
}
```

The execution give me the expected result, -> 1 and 1.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `nb_cust` is not 0 (or negative)?

Comment: Could it be that at some point you assign `s.t_con_cust` to `t_con_cust` (or vice versa) and they start pointing to the same memory?..

Comment: Is there something in `...` that could be changing one or both pointers?

Comment: The code you provide runs as expected.  Your bug is somewhere else.

Comment: Actually, yes.. I assigned t_con_cust == s.t_con_cust somewhere else in my code. So I was searching in the wrong way.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this code

```
fprintf(stdout, "s.t_con_cust[0] -> %d \n", s.t_con_cust[0]);
t_con_cust[0] = 0;
fprintf(stdout, "s.t_con_cust[0] -> %d \n", s.t_con_cust[0]);
```

results in

> s.t_con_cust[0] -> 1
>   s.t_con_cust[0] -> 0

then the only explanation that makes sense is that

```
t_con_cust == s.t_con_cust
```

If that condition was not true then how could assignment to `t_con_cust[0]` affect `s.t_con_cust[0]`?

I predict that when you test the two pointers for equality you will find that they are indeed equal. And then you just need to find the part of the code that assigns the two pointers to the same value.

Comment: indeed.. it was later in my (big) loop, so I didn't search in this way .. Thanks !